# Inverse function stopped working in a loop

Tags: r

I am having a problem. I have the following code:

```
mu_hat<-matrix(list(rep(0,10000)),100)

for (i in 1:k){ 
mu_hat[[i]]<-inv(S_alpha_dim[[i]]+Sigma_inverse[[i]])%*%(m[[i]]+Sigma_inverse[[i]]*mu[i])
}
```

But it is not working properly.From list 77 chance forth it gives me a single scalar:

```
> print(mu_hat)
       [,1]         
  [1,] Numeric,10000
  [2,] Numeric,10000
  [3,] Numeric,10000
  [4,] Numeric,10000
  [5,] Numeric,10000
  [6,] Numeric,10000
  [7,] Numeric,10000
  [8,] Numeric,10000
  [9,] Numeric,10000
 [10,] Numeric,10000
 [11,] Numeric,10000
 [12,] Numeric,10000
 [13,] Numeric,10000
 [14,] Numeric,10000
 [15,] Numeric,10000
 [16,] Numeric,10000
 [17,] Numeric,10000
 [18,] Numeric,10000
 [19,] Numeric,10000
 [20,] Numeric,10000
 [21,] Numeric,10000
 [22,] Numeric,10000
 [23,] Numeric,10000
 [24,] Numeric,10000
 [25,] Numeric,10000
 [26,] Numeric,10000
 [27,] Numeric,10000
 [28,] Numeric,10000
 [29,] Numeric,10000
 [30,] Numeric,10000
 [31,] Numeric,10000
 [32,] Numeric,10000
 [33,] Numeric,10000
 [34,] Numeric,10000
 [35,] Numeric,10000
 [36,] Numeric,10000
 [37,] Numeric,10000
 [38,] Numeric,10000
 [39,] Numeric,10000
 [40,] Numeric,10000
 [41,] Numeric,10000
 [42,] Numeric,10000
 [43,] Numeric,10000
 [44,] Numeric,10000
 [45,] Numeric,10000
 [46,] Numeric,10000
 [47,] Numeric,10000
 [48,] Numeric,10000
 [49,] Numeric,10000
 [50,] Numeric,10000
 [51,] Numeric,10000
 [52,] Numeric,10000
 [53,] Numeric,10000
 [54,] Numeric,10000
 [55,] Numeric,10000
 [56,] Numeric,10000
 [57,] Numeric,10000
 [58,] Numeric,10000
 [59,] Numeric,10000
 [60,] Numeric,10000
 [61,] Numeric,10000
 [62,] Numeric,10000
 [63,] Numeric,10000
 [64,] Numeric,10000
 [65,] Numeric,10000
 [66,] Numeric,10000
 [67,] Numeric,10000
 [68,] Numeric,10000
 [69,] Numeric,10000
 [70,] Numeric,10000
 [71,] Numeric,10000
 [72,] Numeric,10000
 [73,] Numeric,10000
 [74,] Numeric,10000
 [75,] Numeric,10000
 [76,] Numeric,10000
 [77,] 0.0001623316 
 [78,] 0.0001623316 
 [79,] 0.0001623316 
 [80,] 0.0001623316 
 [81,] 0.0001623316 
 [82,] 0.0001623316 
 [83,] 0.0001623316 
 [84,] 0.0001623316 
 [85,] 0.0001623316 
 [86,] 0.0001623316 
 [87,] 0.0001623316 
 [88,] 0.0001623316 
 [89,] 0.0001623316 
 [90,] 0.0001623316 
 [91,] 0.0001623316 
 [92,] 0.0001623316 
 [93,] 0.0001623316 
 [94,] 0.0001623316 
 [95,] 0.0001623316 
 [96,] 0.0001623316 
 [97,] 0.0001623316 
 [98,] 0.0001623316 
 [99,] 0.0001623316 
[100,] 0.0001623316
```

I proceeded to investigate the problem whose root is:

```
> inv(S_alpha_dim[[77]]+Sigma_inverse[[77]])%*%(m[[77]]+Sigma_inverse[[77]]*mu[77])
Error in if (any(apply(abs(X[, 1:n]) <= sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), 1,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

However it works for any value below 77, take for example 1:

```
> inv(S_alpha_dim[[1]]+Sigma_inverse[[1]])
              [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]
  [1,]  0.02315952  0.00877530 -0.00131145  0.00155573 -0.00035146  0.00041928
  [2,]  0.00877530  0.02125184 -0.00353897  0.00014061 -0.00040099  0.00006434
  [3,] -0.00131145 -0.00353897  0.01395759  0.00214469 -0.00014461  0.00033493
  [4,]  0.00155573  0.00014061  0.00214469  0.00932871 -0.00076932  0.00004423
  [5,] -0.00035146 -0.00040099 -0.00014461 -0.00076932  0.00579305  0.00036677
  [6,]  0.00041928  0.00006434  0.00033493  0.00004423  0.00036677  0.00380917
  [7,] -0.00010957 -0.00009191 -0.00004717 -0.00010089 -0.00001488 -0.00014573
  [8,]  0.00014662  0.00002677  0.00010126  0.00001732  0.00006257  0.00000617
  [9,] -0.00004432 -0.00003004 -0.00002029 -0.00002805 -0.00000702 -0.00002250
 [10,]  0.00006203  0.00001219  0.00004024  0.00000766  0.00002120  0.00000269
              [,7]        [,8]        [,9]       [,10]       [,11]       [,12]
  [1,] -0.00010957  0.00014662 -0.00004432  0.00006203 -0.00002181  0.00003009
  [2,] -0.00009191  0.00002677 -0.00003004  0.00001219 -0.00001245  0.00000613
  [3,] -0.00004717  0.00010126 -0.00002029  0.00004024 -0.00001052  0.00001889
  [4,] -0.00010089  0.00001732 -0.00002805  0.00000766 -0.00001071  0.00000379
  [5,] -0.00001488  0.00006257 -0.00000702  0.00002120 -0.00000386  0.00000926
  [6,] -0.00014573  0.00000617 -0.00002250  0.00000269 -0.00000715  0.00000132
  [7,]  0.00254889  0.00007538 -0.00000296  0.00001434 -0.00000167  0.00000531
  [8,]  0.00007538  0.00178521 -0.00003504  0.00000100 -0.00000617  0.00000049
  [9,] -0.00000296 -0.00003504  0.00128354  0.00002012 -0.00000084  0.00000417
 [10,]  0.00001434  0.00000100  0.00002012  0.00095335 -0.00001066  0.00000021
             [,13]       [,14]       [,15]       [,16]       [,17]       [,18]
  [1,] -0.00001229  0.00001612 -0.00000761  0.00000931 -0.00000505  0.00000568
  [2,] -0.00000610  0.00000336 -0.00000337  0.00000196 -0.00000204  0.00000121
  [3,] -0.00000617  0.00000993 -0.00000393  0.00000566 -0.00000266  0.00000343
  [4,] -0.00000497  0.00000205 -0.00000264  0.00000119 -0.00000155  0.00000073
  [5,] -0.00000235  0.00000467 -0.00000153  0.00000260 -0.00000106  0.00000155
  [6,] -0.00000301  0.00000071 -0.00000149  0.00000041 -0.00000083  0.00000025
  [7,] -0.00000103  0.00000249 -0.00000068  0.00000132 -0.00000047  0.00000077
  [8,] -0.00000217  0.00000026 -0.00000098  0.00000015 -0.00000051  0.00000009
  [9,] -0.00000052  0.00000165 -0.00000034  0.00000081 -0.00000024  0.00000045
 [10,] -0.00000208  0.00000011 -0.00000079  0.00000006 -0.00000038  0.00000004
             [,19]       [,20]       [,21]      [,22]      [,23]      [,24]
  [1,] -0.00000352  0.00000363 -0.00000256  2.400e-06 -1.920e-06  1.630e-06
  [2,] -0.00000132  0.00000078 -0.00000090  5.200e-07 -6.400e-07  3.500e-07
  [3,] -0.00000189  0.00000218 -0.00000139  1.430e-06 -1.050e-06  9.700e-07
  [4,] -0.00000098  0.00000047 -0.00000065  3.100e-07 -4.600e-07  2.100e-07
  [5,] -0.00000076  0.00000097 -0.00000056  6.400e-07 -4.300e-07  4.300e-07
  [6,] -0.00000050  0.00000016 -0.00000033  1.100e-07 -2.200e-07  7.000e-08
  [7,] -0.00000034  0.00000047 -0.00000025  3.100e-07 -1.900e-07  2.000e-07
  [8,] -0.00000030  0.00000006 -0.00000019  4.000e-08 -1.200e-07  3.000e-08
  [9,] -0.00000017  0.00000027 -0.00000013  1.700e-07 -1.000e-07  1.100e-07
 [10,] -0.00000021  0.00000002 -0.00000012  2.000e-08 -8.000e-08  1.000e-08
            [,25]      [,26]      [,27]      [,28]      [,29]      [,30]      [,31]
  [1,] -1.480e-06  1.130e-06 -1.160e-06  8.000e-07 -9.300e-07  5.700e-07 -7.600e-07
  [2,] -4.800e-07  2.400e-07 -3.600e-07  1.700e-07 -2.800e-07  1.200e-07 -2.300e-07
  [3,] -8.200e-07  6.700e-07 -6.500e-07  4.700e-07 -5.200e-07  3.400e-07 -4.200e-07
  [4,] -3.300e-07  1.500e-07 -2.500e-07  1.000e-07 -1.900e-07  7.000e-08 -1.500e-07
  [5,] -3.300e-07  2.900e-07 -2.700e-07  2.100e-07 -2.100e-07  1.500e-07 -1.800e-07
  [6,] -1.600e-07  5.000e-08 -1.200e-07  4.000e-08 -9.000e-08  3.000e-08 -7.000e-08
  [7,] -1.500e-07  1.400e-07 -1.200e-07  1.000e-07 -1.000e-07  7.000e-08 -8.000e-08
  [8,] -9.000e-08  2.000e-08 -6.000e-08  1.000e-08 -5.000e-08  1.000e-08 -3.000e-08
  [9,] -8.000e-08  8.000e-08 -6.000e-08  5.000e-08 -5.000e-08  4.000e-08 -4.000e-08
 [10,] -5.000e-08  1.000e-08 -4.000e-08  1.000e-08 -3.000e-08  0.000e+00 -2.000e-08
            [,32]      [,33]      [,34]     [,35]      [,36]      [,37]      [,38]
  [1,]  4.100e-07 -6.300e-07  3.000e-07 -5.20e-07  2.100e-07 -4.400e-07  1.500e-07
  [2,]  9.000e-08 -1.800e-07  6.000e-08 -1.50e-07  5.000e-08 -1.200e-07  3.000e-08
  [3,]  2.400e-07 -3.500e-07  1.800e-07 -2.90e-07  1.300e-07 -2.500e-07  9.000e-08
  [4,]  5.000e-08 -1.200e-07  4.000e-08 -1.00e-07  3.000e-08 -8.000e-08  2.000e-08
  [5,]  1.100e-07 -1.500e-07  8.000e-08 -1.20e-07  5.000e-08 -1.000e-07  4.000e-08
  [6,]  2.000e-08 -5.000e-08  1.000e-08 -4.00e-08  1.000e-08 -4.000e-08  1.000e-08
  [7,]  5.000e-08 -7.000e-08  4.000e-08 -5.00e-08  3.000e-08 -5.000e-08  2.000e-08
  [8,]  1.000e-08 -3.000e-08  0.000e+00 -2.00e-08  0.000e+00 -2.000e-08  0.000e+00
  [9,]  3.000e-08 -3.000e-08  2.000e-08 -3.00e-08  1.000e-08 -2.000e-08  1.000e-08
 [10,]  0.000e+00 -2.000e-08  0.000e+00 -1.00e-08  0.000e+00 -1.000e-08  0.000e+00
            [,39]     [,40]     [,41]     [,42]      [,43]     [,44]      [,45]
  [1,] -3.800e-07 1.100e-07 -3.20e-07 7.000e-08 -2.800e-07 5.000e-08 -2.400e-07
  [2,] -1.100e-07 2.000e-08 -9.00e-08 2.000e-08 -8.000e-08 1.000e-08 -7.000e-08
  [3,] -2.100e-07 6.000e-08 -1.80e-07 4.000e-08 -1.600e-07 3.000e-08 -1.400e-07
  [4,] -7.000e-08 1.000e-08 -6.00e-08 1.000e-08 -5.000e-08 1.000e-08 -4.000e-08
  [5,] -9.000e-08 3.000e-08 -8.00e-08 2.000e-08 -7.000e-08 1.000e-08 -6.000e-08
  [6,] -3.000e-08 0.000e+00 -3.00e-08 0.000e+00 -2.000e-08 0.000e+00 -2.000e-08
  [7,] -4.000e-08 1.000e-08 -3.00e-08 1.000e-08 -3.000e-08 1.000e-08 -3.000e-08
  [8,] -1.000e-08 0.000e+00 -1.00e-08 0.000e+00 -1.000e-08 0.000e+00 -1.000e-08
  [9,] -2.000e-08 1.000e-08 -2.00e-08 0.000e+00 -2.000e-08 0.000e+00 -1.000e-08
 [10,] -1.000e-08 0.000e+00 -1.00e-08 0.000e+00 -1.000e-08 0.000e+00 -1.000e-08
           [,46]     [,47]    [,48]    [,49] [,50]     [,51]     [,52]     [,53]
  [1,] 3.000e-08 -2.10e-07 1.00e-08 -1.9e-07 0e+00 -1.70e-07 -1.00e-08 -1.50e-07
  [2,] 1.000e-08 -6.00e-08 0.00e+00 -5.0e-08 0e+00 -5.00e-08  0.00e+00 -4.00e-08
  [3,] 2.000e-08 -1.20e-07 1.00e-08 -1.1e-07 0e+00 -9.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -8.00e-08
  [4,] 0.000e+00 -4.00e-08 0.00e+00 -3.0e-08 0e+00 -3.00e-08  0.00e+00 -3.00e-08
  [5,] 1.000e-08 -5.00e-08 0.00e+00 -4.0e-08 0e+00 -4.00e-08  0.00e+00 -4.00e-08
  [6,] 0.000e+00 -2.00e-08 0.00e+00 -1.0e-08 0e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08
  [7,] 0.000e+00 -2.00e-08 0.00e+00 -2.0e-08 0e+00 -2.00e-08  0.00e+00 -2.00e-08
  [8,] 0.000e+00 -1.00e-08 0.00e+00 -1.0e-08 0e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08
  [9,] 0.000e+00 -1.00e-08 0.00e+00 -1.0e-08 0e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08
 [10,] 0.000e+00  0.00e+00 0.00e+00  0.0e+00 0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
           [,54]     [,55]     [,56]    [,57]     [,58]     [,59]     [,60]
  [1,] -2.00e-08 -1.30e-07 -2.00e-08 -1.2e-07 -3.00e-08 -1.10e-07 -3.00e-08
  [2,]  0.00e+00 -4.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -3.0e-08 -1.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [3,] -1.00e-08 -8.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -7.0e-08 -2.00e-08 -6.00e-08 -2.00e-08
  [4,]  0.00e+00 -2.00e-08  0.00e+00 -2.0e-08  0.00e+00 -2.00e-08  0.00e+00
  [5,]  0.00e+00 -3.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -3.0e-08 -1.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [6,]  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.0e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00
  [7,]  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.0e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00
  [8,]  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
  [9,]  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.0e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00
 [10,]  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
          [,61]    [,62]  [,63]     [,64]     [,65]     [,66]     [,67]     [,68]
  [1,] -1.0e-07 -4.0e-08 -9e-08 -4.00e-08 -8.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -7.00e-08 -4.00e-08
  [2,] -3.0e-08 -1.0e-08 -3e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [3,] -6.0e-08 -2.0e-08 -5e-08 -2.00e-08 -5.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -3.00e-08
  [4,] -2.0e-08  0.0e+00 -2e-08  0.00e+00 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [5,] -2.0e-08 -1.0e-08 -2e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [6,] -1.0e-08  0.0e+00 -1e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00
  [7,] -1.0e-08  0.0e+00 -1e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [8,]  0.0e+00  0.0e+00  0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
  [9,] -1.0e-08  0.0e+00  0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
 [10,]  0.0e+00  0.0e+00  0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
           [,69]     [,70]     [,71]     [,72]     [,73]     [,74]     [,75]
  [1,] -7.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -6.00e-08 -5.00e-08 -6.00e-08 -5.00e-08 -5.00e-08
  [2,] -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08
  [3,] -4.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -3.00e-08
  [4,] -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [5,] -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [6,] -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08
  [7,] -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [8,]  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
  [9,]  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
 [10,]  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
           [,76]     [,77]     [,78]     [,79]     [,80]     [,81]     [,82]
  [1,] -5.00e-08 -5.00e-08 -5.00e-08 -5.00e-08 -6.00e-08 -5.00e-08 -6.00e-08
  [2,] -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [3,] -3.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -4.00e-08
  [4,] -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [5,] -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08
  [6,]  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00
  [7,] -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08
  [8,]  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
  [9,]  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
 [10,]  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
           [,83]     [,84]     [,85]     [,86]     [,87]     [,88]     [,89]
  [1,] -4.00e-08 -6.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -7.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -8.00e-08 -4.00e-08
  [2,] -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -2.00e-08
  [3,] -2.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -5.00e-08 -2.00e-08
  [4,] -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08
  [5,] -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [6,] -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08
  [7,]  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00
  [8,]  0.00e+00  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08
  [9,]  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00
 [10,]  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00 -1.00e-08  0.00e+00 -2.00e-08
           [,90]     [,91]     [,92]     [,93]    [,94]     [,95]     [,96]
  [1,] -9.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -1.00e-07 -5.00e-08 -1.1e-07 -5.00e-08 -1.10e-07
  [2,] -2.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -2.0e-08 -6.00e-08 -1.00e-08
  [3,] -6.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -7.00e-08 -2.00e-08 -9.0e-08 -2.00e-08 -1.60e-07
  [4,] -1.00e-08 -3.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -1.0e-08 -1.10e-07  4.60e-07
  [5,] -3.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -4.00e-08 -1.00e-08 -1.0e-07 -3.20e-07  6.00e-08
  [6,]  0.00e+00 -2.00e-08  0.00e+00 -6.00e-08  2.1e-07  5.00e-08  0.00e+00
  [7,] -2.00e-08  0.00e+00 -5.00e-08 -1.60e-07  4.0e-08  0.00e+00  1.00e-08
  [8,]  0.00e+00 -3.00e-08  1.10e-07  3.00e-08  0.0e+00  1.00e-08  0.00e+00
  [9,] -3.00e-08 -9.00e-08  2.00e-08  0.00e+00  1.0e-08  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
 [10,]  6.00e-08  2.00e-08  0.00e+00  1.00e-08  0.0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
          [,97]     [,98]     [,99] [,100]
  [1,] -4.0e-08 -7.00e-08 -1.01e-06  0e+00
  [2,] -1.0e-07  8.80e-07  1.00e-08  0e+00
  [3,] -6.8e-07  3.00e-08  0.00e+00  0e+00
  [4,]  6.0e-08  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0e+00
  [5,]  0.0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0e+00
  [6,]  1.0e-08  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0e+00
  [7,]  0.0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0e+00
  [8,]  0.0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0e+00
  [9,]  0.0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0e+00
 [10,]  0.0e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0e+00
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 90 rows ]
```

The matrices I am referring are the following ones: I cannot post the matrices since I have a character limit.

There is no apparent difference in the nature of both matrices but the inverse function is not working for the "77 onwards " matrices. I do not know the reason as there are no NAs. I even tried Ginv but the problem persists.

I could try to create a case, but I cannot because the problem seems to be with the matrices I have. So I do not understand the error message I am getting.

**Question:**

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

If someone needs the matrices, I am happy to provide them. Just indicate me how should I do it.

```
#SDE simulation

time_B<-1.0

n_B<-100

t<-100
dt<-1/100

X=rep(0,100)
for (i in 1:100){
  X<-X+(-(0.5)*X*(X-1)*(X+1))*dt+sqrt(dt)*rnorm(n_B,0,1)
  
  
}


plot(X)+lines(X)




#Thetas for all possible 50 alphas

k<-100

Theta<-matrix(0,k,k)
alpha<-seq(1,k,1)
for (j in alpha){
  for (i in 1:k){Theta[i,j]<-i^(-0.5-j)}
}

print(Theta)


#Theta multiplied by a matrix of random variables

Z<-matrix(rnorm(10000,0,1),k,k)

Theta_estimator<-Theta*Z

#Sigma covariance matrix

n<-100

Sigma<-lapply(seq(n), function(k) (diag(seq(n)))^(-2*k-1))

diag(Sigma[[1]])
Sigma[[1]][100,100]







#The average of the prior for each individual alpha given by vector mu
mu_sum<-rep(0,k)
for(j in 1:k){
  for (i in 1:k){mu_sum[j]<-mu_sum[j]+Theta_estimator[i,j]}
}

mu=mu_sum/k

print(mu)



#Building the Basis of periodic functions
#rows for different times,columns for different k
Basis1<-matrix(0,t,k)
for(j in 1:t){
  for (i in 1:k){
    if(i%% 2==1) {Basis1[j,i]=sqrt(2)*cos(2*pi*i*j*dt)}
    
    else{Basis1[j,i]=sqrt(2)*sin(2*pi*i*j*dt)}
    
    
  }
}

print(Basis1)

print(X)
#Integral wiht respect to time

Basis<-t(Basis1)
m_l<-t(Basis1)*X

m<-rowSums(m_l)

print(m)

#Stochastic Integral
#Due to the combinations the following matrix is defined with vectors inside

S_ll<-matrix(list(rep(NA,t)),k^2,t)

for (i in 1:k){
  for (j in 1:k){
    S_ll[[i,j]]<-Basis[i,]*Basis[j,]
    
  }  
}


Time_vec<-c(0,100)
for (i in 1:t){
  Time_vec[i]<-i*dt
}

S_dt<-matrix(list(rep(NA,100)),k^2,t)

for (i in 1:k){
  for (j in 1:t){
    S_dt[[i,j]]<-S_ll[[i,j]]*Time_vec
  }
}   


print(S_dt)  




S_dt[1,1]

S<-matrix(0,k,k)
for (i in 1:k){
  for (j in 1:t){
    S[i,j]<-sum(S_dt[[i,j]])
  }
}   



#Likelihood implementation 

#Increase the dimension of S to a point it the same as Sigma_1 for all alphas
m_apha_dim<-matrix(rep(list(m),k),k)

#Increase the dimension of S to a point it the same as Sigma_1 for all alphas

S_alpha_dim<-matrix(rep(list(S),k),k)

print(S_alpha_dim)

#Package with inversion functions

install.packages("matlib")
library(matlib)


#Computation of mu_hat

Sigma_inverse<-lapply(seq(n), function(k) (diag(seq(n)))^(2*k+1))

mu_hat<-matrix(list(rep(0,10000)),100)

for (i in 1:k){ 
mu_hat[[i]]<-inv(S_alpha_dim[[i]]+Sigma_inverse[[i]])%*%(m[[i]]+Sigma_inverse[[i]]*mu[i])
}
```

Comment: So, your actual issue is that `inv(S_alpha_dim[[77]]+Sigma_inverse[[77]])` returns an error. I don't think we can help you without having the matrix `S_alpha_dim[[77]]+Sigma_inverse[[77]]`. Can you add the output of `dput(S_alpha_dim[[77]]+Sigma_inverse[[77]])` to your question?

Comment: @Roland         Thanks for the comment. How do I proceed with dput?

Comment: @Roland If I do dput it generates a code with a lot of elements so that I cannot upload.

Comment: @Roland I have just uploaded the code. So that now you can reproduce my results.

Comment: `t` and `k` are not defined.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your support insofar! ```t=100``` and ```k=100``` are both 100

Comment: Please fix your code. I'm still getting errors because stuff is not defined. Restart R and run the code you provide to ensure that it is reproducible for others.

Comment: @Roland I have uploaded the entire code. Now it must run.

Comment: `matlib::inverse` doesn't implement an approach I would use (Gaussian elimination, really?). `solve(S_alpha_dim[[77]]+Sigma_inverse[[77]])` tells you that your issue is singularity.

Comment: Also, why are you inverting matrices? Usually it's best to avoid doing that.

Comment: @Roland               I need to do it for theoretical purposes. If I do not invert with a function, then how should I invert?

Comment: @Roland I have just computed the determinant, it is infinite.

Comment: Calculate an inverse for theoretical purposes? What does  that even mean?

Comment: @Roland It is the theoretical formula I am trying to implement. I cannot compute the inverse of a matrix of this size by hand. Unless you have an analytical way to do it.

Comment: I can't comment further. I can only say that calculating the inverse of a matrix reliably is a computational challenge. It's also usually not necessary and should be avoided since solving a matrix equation works better. If you must invert a matrix, don't use Gaussian elimination, which is probably the worst algorithm for this.